# Can't Connect OpenShift MySql from tomcat project

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, openshift

I'm working on an openshift tomcat project by using mysql as backend I am trying to connect database and it is not connecting and shows error message **"Communications link failure Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago"** I have connected database using this code

```
try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
                //return(ex.getMessage());              
            }
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST,MYSQL_USERNAME,MYSQL_PASSWORD); 

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            return(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return "success";
```

I've provided the database url by hardcoding the database IP and port,when I print **System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST");** I'm getting null value. please tell me anyone the error

Comment: Could you check the environmental variables in your gear? Connect using ssh, then: env | grep OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST

Comment: can you please expand your answer little more ?,please share any demo links or documentation available

Comment: Check this link to know how to access to your gear: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-remote-connection.html After that, from the console execute: env | grep OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are facing occurs when your java code is unable to connect to MySQL server. There is one more way, check if your MySQL is up and running. You can get your MySQL server's ip by

```
rhc port-forward -a <mysql_gear_name>
```

You can then explicitly give that IP in `DriverManager.getConnection`

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, run rhc port-forward to access databases or internal ports directly.

Eg :

```
rhc port-forward -a <name of the gear including mysql db>
```